# File limits getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE) failed

Tags: linux, files, limit, lsof, segmentation-fault

(32-bit system)

[Posted a Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180063/98945) earlier regarding Chrome crashing because of exhausted limit in open files.

Chrome has since run more smooth, (after increasing limit), but still crashes from time to time.

### Crash reports

Looking at the crash reports it repeatedly have something like:

```
SegvAnalysis:
 Segfault happened at: 0xb616c30f:  movl   $0x1337,0x0
 PC (0xb616c30f) ok
 source "$0x1337" ok
 destination "0x0" (0x00000000) not located in a known VMA region (needed writable region)!
 Stack memory exhausted (SP below stack segment)
SegvReason: writing NULL VMA
```

Watchdog entries in log typically say:

```
... Watchdog[3100]: segfault at 0 ip b613437f sp af8e8cc0 error 6 in chrome[b20d5000+5689000]
```

From `/proc/[PID]/maps` in crash file there is:

```
bfd58000-bfd78000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

which concludes 128K stack? (`0xbfd78000 - 0xbfd58000 = 131072`)

From `/proc/[PID]/status` in crash file there is:

```
 FDSize:    1024
```

though I have set soft limit to 32K.

But guess this is for the process caught in the report and not the children etc.

---

### Limits error

Now, after latest update to Version 40.0.2214.94 there is a new issue. After a while (I'm running chrome from shell) there are repeated entries of:

```
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE) failed
```

I have set limit for open files 32768 by:

```
ulimit -Sn 32768
```

---

### lsof counting

I find it hard to detect how many files Chrome actually have open due to spawning and reuse etc. but it looks like it is using quite a few. `losof` includes anything but out of curiosity I did a test to see how many (greedy) entries was added.

Before starting Chrome `losf | wc -l` yielded about 55K lines. That was with FireFox open holding 80+ tabs in multiple windows + quite a lot of other applications.

After starting Chrome the lsof count is going kind of high:

```
                      lsof | wc -l
Pre chrome         :  55,524
 1 window   1 tab  :  79,820
 1 window  15 tabs : 105,308
 2 windows 30 tabs : 141,076
 3 windows 40 tabs : 187,285
```

Trying to only looking at processes named `chrome` (now) with 1 window 2 tabs:

```
sudo lsof -a -p $(pgrep chrome | paste -sd "," -) | wc -l
```

gives 4380.

---

#### Question:

My question is if this could have anything to do with the `getrlimit` errors, (and / or perhaps the SigSegv's).

Is that amount of entries in `lsof` normal / to be expected for an application like Chrome?

Is there something I can do to *"fix"* the `getrlimit` errors?

Is it perhaps because I set soft limit to high?